# how to send an attachment through outlook using c# winform application

Tags: c#

hi 
i am using a winform appplication.i took a button.if i click a button it should send the an excel attachment to To,CC,Bcc.How can i do this?
plz help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really is no reason for COM interop as others have suggested. Look into the .NET System.Net.Mail namespace.

The relevant classes are:

- [MailMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx)
- [Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx)
- [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)

There is a complete C# example of sending an xls attachement in the [Attachment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) class documentation.

```
// Specify the file to be attached and sent.
// This example assumes that a file named Data.xls exists in the current working directory.
string file = "data.xls";

// Create a message and set up the recipients.
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
   "jane@contoso.com",
   "ben@contoso.com",
   "Quarterly data report.",
   "See the attached spreadsheet.");

// Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

// Add time stamp information for the file.
ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);

// Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
message.Attachments.Add(data);

//Send the message.
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);

// Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
client.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use Outlook to send your email, you could simple use the COM-Object, e.g. like this:

```
dynamic app = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Outlook.Application"));
dynamic email = app.CreateItem(0);
email.Subject = "Subject";
email.Body = "Text";
email.To = "email@email.com";
email.Save();
email.Attachments.Add(@"E:\MyFile.txt");

email.Display(true); //use this to display the Outlook-window
email.Send(); //use this to send the email directly
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application olkApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem olkMail = (MailItem)olkApp.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);                
olkMail.Subject = "Test mail";
olkMail.To = "xxx@yyy.com";
olkMail.Body = "Hi";
olkMail.Attachments.Add("D:\\Data\\report.xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue, 1, "Report");
olkMail.Save();//saves the mail in drafts with out sending
//olkMail.Send();//Sends the mail
MessageBox.Show("Mail sent");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MailItem.Attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb147604.aspx) property.